# I have an existing project called Craft cms v3.3, what should I do if I want to run it at local?(Mac OS)

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, control-panel, config, projectconfig

I currently have a project that is definitely craft cms v3. I want to run it but this is the first time I keep stressing over it. Please help me
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added an answer to point you in the right direction, but this question is too broad to be answered. Please read the tutorial, try to follow it, and ask specific questions with enough context if you run into problems.

Comment: I want to start this project, I used ddev... but it didn't work. This is my first time approaching craft cms. You can sp for me ?

Comment: I don't know what `sp` means. If you want help, you need to be way more specific. What have you tried so far? What step are you stuck on? What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: sp = support .Currently I have an existing project that has been created in craft cms 3.3. I want it to run on my browser, what should I do?

Comment: Can you leave your email so I can send you how I set it up for you to see and help me?

Comment: Please follow the tutorial I linked to in my answer. I'm not available for freelance work at the moment – if you want someone to take over maintenance, I suggest you reach out in the `#jobs` channel on [Discord](https://craftcms.com/community) or find a [partner agency](https://craftcms.com/partners).

Answer (score 3):

Follow the [getting started tutorial](https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/) to learn how to set up a local development environment. The only thing that's different is that instead of running `composer create-project craftcms/craft`, you use the contents of your project folder.